# Why Flowable cannot be subscribed to Observer?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am learning rxJava in android, hence pretty new to it. I am using examples from following site.

https://www.androidhive.info/RxJava/rxjava-understanding-observables/

Please refer to the flowable example. The following is my code

```
Flowable<Integer> flowableObservable = getFlowableObservable();

    SingleObserver<Integer> observer = getFlowableObserver();
    flowableObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(observer);
```

///////////////////

```
private Flowable<Integer> getFlowableObservable() {
    return Flowable.range(1, 100);
}
private SingleObserver<Integer> getFlowableObserver() {
    return new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe");
          //  disposable = d;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + integer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
}
```

So it is giving me error in the line

```
 SingleObserver<Integer> observer = getFlowableObserver();
flowableObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(observer);
```

> error is cannot resolve the method subscribe

Th library I am using is

> compile group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.1.9'
>       implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1

So what is the reason,I believe I have copied almost the same code from the site ??
Thank you.

Comment: Please see this table for source-consumer types: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#base-class-vs-base-type .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed up the [source-consumer types](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#base-class-vs-base-type) a bit: `Flowable` requires a `Subscriber`. Try this:

```java
Flowable<Integer> flowableObservable = getFlowableObservable();
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv ------------------------------------------------
   Subscriber<Integer> observer = getFlowableObserver();

flowableObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(observer);


private Flowable<Integer> getFlowableObservable() {
    return Flowable.range(1, 100);
}

private Subscriber<Integer> getFlowableObserver() {
//             vvvvvvvvvv ---------------------------------------------
    return new Subscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription d) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSubscribe");
          // request is required to start items flowing!
          // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv --------------------------------
            d.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        //          vvvvvv --------------------------------------------
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + integer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        //          vvvvvvvvvv ----------------------------------------
        public void onComplete(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
SingleObserver<Integer> observer = getFlowableObserver();
flowableObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(observer);
```

And the code from the tutorial is not the same:

```
flowableObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .reduce(0, new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer result, Integer number) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Result: " + result + ", new number: " + number);
            return result + number;
        }
    })
    .subscribe(observer);
```

The method [observeOn](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#subscribeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) returns a [Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html) so if you call `subscribe` right after it, it is the same as doing this:

```
Flowable<Integer> resultOfObserveOn = flowableObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
resultOfObserveOn.subscribe(observer); //this is the subscribe method from the Flowable class
```

If you use [reduce](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#reduce-R-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-), it does

```
Single<Integer> resultOfReduce = flowableObservable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .reduce(0, new BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(Integer result, Integer number) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Result: " + result + ", new number: " + number);
            return result + number;
        }
    });
resultOfReduce.subscribe(observer); //this is the subscribe method from the Single class
```

Comment: actually I was using the same variable earlier I mean observer, still the same issue.

Comment: My simple observable works absolutely fine. Issue is only with flowable

Comment: I'm not a Rx expert, but you removed the reduce function, which returns a Single, so now you have only observeOn which returns a Flowable. As a consequence, the subscribe method you call might not be the same... Did you test it with the complete example, using reduce as well ?

Comment: great.... Yeah that was the reason, but can some explain me the significance of that ?? Also how to use it without reduce method ??

Comment: This is still conflating a lot of unrelated RxJava components. Please see this table for source-consumer types: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#base-class-vs-base-type

Comment: @akarnokd, can you be more specific ? Which components are conflating where ?

Comment: @akarnokd btw how does one use it without reduce method ??

Comment: @Pritish which reduce method? Your question doesn't have a reduce call.

Comment: @akarnokd actually that is the answer of my question, which 2Dee gave, since I was not using the reduce function mentioned the example link provided by me, it was not letting me subscribe the observer. Once I used it it let me subscribe

Comment: So what is the significance of it, and what other kind of observables can I use with Flowable

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#reduce-R-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) and also [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html), reduce aggregates items emitted by the source to a single result, thus SingleObserver is used in the example. If you don't reduce/aggregate the items emitted by the source, you need to use a regular Subscriber as the observer.